# Vlookup Formula in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, excel-2016

I have an Excel sheet with locked cells. Some cells are unlocked to input values. There are many values to input therefore I'm trying to write a Macro that will: select the unlocked cells in the Active Sheet and fill the selected cells with a Vlookup formula that looks up the input values based on the first column and relevant rows in the same sheet from a table on a separate sheet. I have tried the below:

```
Sub SelectUnlockedCells()
'Update 20130830
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Locked = False Then
        If OutRng.Count = 0 Then
            Set OutRng = Rng
        Else
            Set OutRng = Union(OutRng, Rng)
        End If
    End If
Next
If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("A" & ActiveRow.Value, Worksheets(2).Columns("A:C").Select, Worksheets(2).Columns(3).Select, False)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I know my problem occurs in the last 4 lines in the Vlookup Worksheet Function, because if I say:

```
If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng = 1 + 1
```

The unlocked input cells are imputed correctly as 2. Therefore I suspect my Vlookup object selection is not correct.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution I found was as I suspected - object referencing inside the vlookup was wrong. Also, the Application Worksheet Function was redundant in this case. In the third last line solution was:

```
If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng = "=VLOOKUP(A11,'Sheet1'!Table1,3,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not putting a formula in those cells at all, you're trying to put a value in there, and the syntax you have is completely wrong for that anyway. Try:

```
If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RC1,'" & worksheets(2).name & "'!C1:C3,3,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Thanks, Rory. This helped somewhat. As I suspected the biggest thing was my syntax object referencing inside the vlookup that was wrong. Will post what I found to work